# Does python suffer from circular dependency issues?

Tags: python

Im getting this stack trace:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitflow/gitflow/flow_conditions.py", line 3, in <module>
    from gitflow.flow_config import ConfigManager
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/flow_config.py", line 19, in <module>
    from gitflow.flow_workflow import FlowCommand, WorkflowCommand
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/flow_workflow.py", line 5, in <module>
    from gitflow.flow_conditions import ConditionFactory
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/flow_conditions.py", line 3, in <module>
    from gitflow.flow_config import ConfigManager
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/flow_config.py", line 19, in <module>
    from gitflow.flow_workflow import FlowCommand, WorkflowCommand
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/flow_workflow.py", line 5, in <module>
    from gitflow.flow_conditions import ConditionFactory
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/flow_conditions.py", line 3, in <module>
    from gitflow.flow_config import ConfigManager
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/flow_config.py", line 19, in <module>
    from gitflow.flow_workflow import FlowCommand, WorkflowCommand
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/flow_workflow.py", line 5, in <module>
    from gitflow.flow_conditions import ConditionFactory
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitflow/flow_conditions.py", line 3, in <module>
```

I can't find a thing wrong with my code and it leaves me to an idea that I wasn't sure was a problem in Python.  Circular dependencies.   Does python handle circular dependencies well or should I refactor them out to see if that solves the problem.

thanks.

Comment: Looks like rinfinite recursion. Could you show your code please?

Comment: Do you really have a gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow/gitflow... directory structure?

Comment: Looks like a path issue, each import tries to go a level deeper for `gitflow` directory...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have this:

```
# in foo.py
from bar import cat

# in bar.py
from foo import dog
```

That creates an infinite loop of both modules trying to import each other. Python specifically  does not handle this problem as it is generally understood that circular dependencies are a mark of bad design.

Comment: -1 Wrong. It doesn't loop indefinitely, it just fails to import one of the two names even if both are defined in the respective files after the imports. Oh, and it imports one of the two modules twice under two different names. Modules are stored in `sys.modules` before the module body is executed.

Comment: Ok, I thought that was the problem.  I just wasn't sure if Python handled it in the interpreter or not.  Guess I have to move some stuff around.  Thanks

Comment: @scphantm: that doesn't really look like the problem that you're having, though.

Comment: It was.  I combined 3 py files into one and everything came alive.  I know this object model is getting away from me at the moment and I had one or two circles in it.  Im just dumping everything into one file for the time being.  Once I know how this thing is going to shape out I will clean it up.